# What should I do to a quad remesh only on specific parts?

Tags: retopology, remesh

I'm new to blender. What I'm trying to do right now is to get the poly counts of the face of my character down, but leave the poly counts of the eye, nose and lip areas untouched.

I've tried doing a vertex paint on these areas and then while doing quad checking *Preserve Mask Paint*, but it still applies to all.

There are certain steps I'm missing.
And also when you could provide me with other ways to approach this, that'll be awesome.